# Is it still possible to install global plugins in Grails

Tags: grails, plugins

In earlier version of Grails, it was possible to install global plugins so that it will be installed for every application by default.

Is it still possible with latest Grails versions? I don't see anything in documentation.

Comment: I don't know how it was installed global plugins. Can you show how it was done?

Comment: Earlier it was possible to install global plugins using command 
grails install-plugin xx -global

See global plugins section in http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/1.3.8/guide/single.html

Answer (score 0):

I have looked the link provide by you.

In Grails 1.3.8, we can use `grails install-plugin` command.

In Grails 2.2.2, it has message

> Plugins should be installed by listing them in BuildConfig.groovy with
>   the appropriate scope instead of using install-plugin.

In Grails 2.3.1 and 2.5.0, it has message

> DEPRECATED: The install-plugin command is deprecated
>
> Plugins should be
>   installed by listing them in BuildConfig.groovy with the appropriate
>   scope instead of using install-plugin.

But in latest Grails documentation command line part, it does not have `install-plugin` command. The latest documentation does not have other commands such as

```
install-dependency
install-plugin
install-templates
```

So it seems the command has been removed from latest Grails i.e. 3.0.x. And it has always suggested to use BuildConfig.groovy instead of install-plugin. So I think it is not possible to install global plugins.

I have not install Grails 3.0.1 to check if the command `install-plugin` exists but it may not be in latest Grails.

Comment: I know that command has been deprecated and now dependencies have to be configured in BuildConfig, that is why I have asked this question, if there's an alternative. Docs says command has been deprecated it does not say global plugins has been deprecated

Comment: I don't think there is any alternative for this because it is bad practice not to have dependency defined in project.

Comment: Dude I am not talking about not defining dependency in BuildConfig, i am talking about global plugins